# Mulesoft_ passing client id and Client_secret under HTTP header

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a requirement where I need to add both client id and client_secret under HTTP headers(under attribute,headers)
I tried to use the below code and unfortunately, it is not working, so please check and guide us to get the expected code.

Transform message create an attribute and applied the below DataWeave code:

```js
output application/java
---
{
    headers: {
        client_id: '68eee04d10774836b6e5c40189ed3efb',
        client_secret: '149541B02E23487EBE517708496a2920'
}
```

And in the consume connector header part, I have added the below line code.
Attributes.headers

Comment: What is the 'consume connector'? There is no connector by that name. Please share the operations in XML text from the flows so we can really understand what the application is doing.

Comment: <wsc:consume doc:name="Invoke Clasification Rules Web Service Consumer"
   doc:id="ac502364-5dba-48d7-906a-dabed51f3d04" config-ref="Classification_Service_Web_Service_Consumer_Config"
   operation="classifyActivity" >
  </wsc:consume>
and in the header part i have added like attributes.headers

Comment: Please edit the question to add the details.

Comment: I hope I shared the necessary details to look at and let m know in case any additional details are required.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say without seeing exactly what the application is doing but I suspect you are mixing SOAP headers with HTTP headers. HTTP Headers go into the transport headers element.

Example assuming both kind of headers in different variables. Note that you can set each header individually or pass an object which contains them all:

```xml
<wsc:consume doc:name="Consume"  config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" operation="GetContent">
    <wsc:message>
        <wsc:headers><![CDATA[#[vars.soapHeaders]]]></wsc:headers>
    </wsc:message>
    <wsc:transport-headers>
        <wsc:transport-header key="client_id" value="#[vars.httpHeaders.client_id]" />
        <wsc:transport-header key="client_secret" value="#[vars.httpHeaders.client_secret]" />
    </wsc:transport-headers>
</wsc:consume>
```